# How does nginx serve my site once the request reaches my ip address?

Tags: nginx, http

[image]

I'm trying to understand the details in step by step fashion of what happens when I request a page from a django site running on my VPS as I work through https://www.obeythetestinggoat.com/book/chapter_manual_deployment.html

If I understand correctly when I browse to 'mysite.com' A dns lookup occurs redirecting my request to the ip address in the A record which is my ubuntu server vps server with nginx running. My nginx config file would look like:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name mysite.com;

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://localhost:8000;
    }
}
```

I'm guessing that at this point nginx (listening on port 80) is able to look at the request and associated http headers and match the request to the appropriate nginx site-enabled config file. Is this simple mental model correct. What major points am I missing?

Comment: You have understood it correctly. With plain http, nginx matches HTTP Host header to find the virtual host block to use. With https, nginx uses information from SNI field in TLS negotiation to find the virtual host.

Comment: Thank you . I also found https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/understanding-nginx-server-and-location-block-selection-algorithms

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have answered your own question! I would recommend checking out your logs too in: 
`/var/log/nginx`

Logs are an awesome way to see how things are working under the hood